# Compare 2 url Hostname using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to compare 2 URL hostname and categorise them as equal or not equal.

For example,
[www.abcd.com/xyz](http://www.abcd.com/xyz)    and https://www.abcd.com/def   Should be treated as equal
[www.abcd.com](http://www.abcd.com) and https://www.abcd.com/xyz Should be treated as equal
However,
[www.abcd.com/xyz](http://www.abcd.com/xyz) and https://www.abcdef/xyz Should be treated as unequal.

I only want to categorise them into equal and unequal.
One column contains url without https and 1 is with https

Comment: https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/database_guides/Practical_PostgreSQL_database/c7547_002.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
regexp_match(url1, 'www.*/') = regexp_match(url2, 'www.*/')
```